# how convert htaccess deny rule to IIS url rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, http, iis, mod-rewrite, https

I am converting .htaccess file to rewrite rules in IIS to convert from http to https,
all the rules are being converted which starts with `RewriteCond` but `deny from all` is not converted

I want to convert this htaccess rule to IIS rewrite rule

```
<Files ~ "\.log$">
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Is there any other way to convert it? or I doing something wrong.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

to convert this rule you could use the request filtering feature of iis or URL rewrite.

```
<configuration>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".log" allowed="false" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

using url rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Protect files and directories from prying eyes" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="\.log$" /> 
    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access is forbidden." /> 
</rule>
```

for more detail please refer this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig#request-filtering